# Hidden text element within centered absolute div

Tags: html, css, position

I'm having trouble getting a h2 header to appaer within an absolutely positioned element. I've ran through the list of possible errors, but still can't seem to find the answer. The h2 element, after inspecting the screen, has a height of 0 for some reason.

[Here's a codepen link](https://codepen.io/MoSheikh/pen/vmrqxq)

HTML:

```
  <div class="gallery">

      <img class='gallery-image' src='https://dummyimage.com/200x400/000000/ffffff'>
      <img class='gallery-image' src='https://dummyimage.com/200x400/000000/ffffff'>
      <img class='gallery-image' src='https://dummyimage.com/200x400/000000/ffffff'>
      <img class='gallery-image' src='https://dummyimage.com/200x400/000000/ffffff'>
      <a class='call-action' href='#'>
        <h2>Shop Now.</h2>
      </a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 0;

  img {

    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;

    }

  }

}

$call-action-width: 150px;
$call-action-height: 50px;

.call-action {

  width: $call-action-width;
  height: $call-action-height;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5%;

  h2 {

    position: relative;
    color: black;
    font-size: 2em;

  }

}
```

Sorry if the answer is obvious - I've just returned to practicing coding and I'm extremely rough.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is another outlook on how to write the markup and styles: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/3a09d48fc68bb205008d3e4d585cae1b/ I couldn't help myself. : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your `font-size`. You can't have an `em` font within a `position: absolute` `<div>`, as `em` is relative to the **parent** element.

Simply swapping to a fixed-size font (such as `px`) fixes the problem. I've created a new pen showcasing this [**here**](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/OmEKPm).

Unfortunately this means that your font can't be responsive.  If you want responsive font, you'll either have to use a few media queries, or restructure your HTML so that the `<h2>` element has a `position: relative` parent (so you can use `em`).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: the `rem` unit can still be used, which is similar to `em`, but is relative to the root (html) as opposed to it's parent ([more info here](https://zellwk.com/blog/rem-vs-em/)). This may be a better substitute than `px` or media queries.

Comment: The em font size would work except the parent element has a font-size of 0. I don't think absolute positioning matters when it comes to em and parents

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That was it!